# Deploying Event Receiver globally after local development

Tags: 2010, solution-package

I am a beginner with Visual Studio and Sharepoint development in general.

I am trying to deploy an event receiver wsp file that I wrote to production for the first time. However, after I have installed and deployed the solution, the event receiver does not fire.

Thinking there was a problem with my code, I went back and created a simple event receiver project that fires upon deleting an Announcement list item and simply set properties.Cancel = true; in the event handler code. When I deployed this as a global solution, my delete action was not intercepted, either.

Is there something basic I'm missing that needs to be changed when I go from my local sharepoint instance to a remote one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you enable the feature that contains the Event Receiver? (At whatever level your Feature is scoped to?)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by enable the feature. I have enabled the solution on the farm, meaning it's marked as deployed in the solution management page. Is there something else I have to enable as well?

Comment: In your Project, open the Feature (in the Features folder of the Solution Explorer).  You should see a Scope drop down list to let you know where it is scoped to.  Probably Web.  So, if it is Web, goto the Site Features page on the Settings page of your site that you want to enable this for and enable your feature (which the name of you will see when you open the Feature in your project).

Comment: If it is Site, you'll need to goto the Site Collection Features page at the root of your site collection.

Comment: Thank you so much, John, this fixed the problem. I was not aware that site/web level deployment happened in two steps like this and had not read it anywhere I had been looking before. Really appreciate it!